# cannot insert contents of text files into database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert the contents of some text files into database, but it failed. please help me, thank you very much. :)

```
<?php

function saveContent($url){
set_time_limit(0);
   foreach ($url as $file =>$files) {
      $handle= fopen($files, "r") or die ('can not open file');
      $content = file_get_contents($files);

      //insert into database

      $q0 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_document (doc_id, namefiles, content) VALUES('','$files','$content') ");
      fclose($handle);
   }
}

$path_to_check = 'C:/Appserv/www/textsumm2/textsumm/try/';
$url = glob($path_to_check.'*.txt');
$a = saveContent($url);

?>
```

Comment: What contents is inside file? What is `content` field type?

Comment: what are contents of your text file ? There is a high possibility of an incorrect query syntax being generated.

Comment: Don't forget to escape single quotes `'` from `$content` and `$file` before insert it into your db.

Comment: In what you failed, what are your error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the content of your files to prevent characters that cause an invalid SQL syntax.

You can use [real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use mysql_real_escape_string() :

$content = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($files));